# Empty view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn/refresh my AngularJS knowledge, by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM).

I'm now trying to complete the section on views and routing.  However when I load the main.html page, no view is displayed. All I see is:

```
Before view! After view!
```

The chrome dev console is also completely empty (no errors/warnings etc).

So what am I missing?

I'm running it through an 'express' node.js server locally on my Win7 64bit pc.  I'm accessing the page in the browser using http://localhost:9000/main.html

I downloaded the 1.5.8 versions of angular.js and angular-route.min.js and placed them in the same directory as main.html.

Trying: http://localhost:9000/view1.html displays the content of the view successfully.

This is the main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
    <body>

        Before view!

        <div ng-view></div>

        After view!

        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            var demoApp=angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute']);

            demoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/view1',
                        {
                            controller: 'SimpleController',
                            templateURL: '/view1.html'
                        })
                    .when('/view2',
                        {
                            controller: 'SimpleController',
                            templateURL: '/view2.html'
                        })
                    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });       

            });

            var controllers= {};

            controllers.SimpleController= function($scope) {
                        $scope.customers=[
                            {name:'John Smith', city: 'New York'},
                            {name: 'Bob Jones', city: 'London'},
                            {name:'David Peters', city: 'Sydney'}
                        ];
                        $scope.addCustomer=function() {
                            $scope.customers.push( { name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city: $scope.newCustomer.city });
                        }
                    };

            demoApp.controller(controllers);

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here's view1.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>View 1</h2>
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="filter.name" />

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name | orderBy:'name'">{{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    Customer Name: <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name" /> 
    <br />
    Customer City: <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city" /> 
    <br/>
    <button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>

    <a href="#/view2">View 2</a>

</div>
```

view2.html is just a simpler version of view1.html

Comment: I think your view is not call. Make sure you are call controller in right way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have  closer look at the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following code:

```
  demoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider
                        .when('/view1',
                            {
                                controller: 'SimpleController',
                                templateURL: '/view1.html'
                            })
                        .when('/view2',
                            {
                                controller: 'SimpleController',
                                templateURL: '/view2.html'
                            })
                        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });       

                });
```

with the following code:

```
demoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider
                        .when('/view1',
                            {
                                controller: 'SimpleController',
                                templateUrl: 'view1.html'
                            })
                        .when('/view2',
                            {
                                controller: 'SimpleController',
                                templateUrl: 'view2.html'
                            })
                        .otherwise({ redirectTo: 'view1' });       

    });
```

Replaced "templateURL" in your code with "templateUrl" because it is case sensitive.

Comment: That was what I missed!  Thanks.  I hate it when languages turn acronyms (eg URL) into capitalized words (eg Url).   It's very annoying that it doesn't even log something like 'unknown identifier' to the console.

Comment: Do you know if there is a debug version of angular.js that logs extra information and errors like this?  Would be very useful while learning.  I've tried the minified and non-minified versions and neither logged anything for this error to the console.

Comment: I second that.
But I don't know any such debugging version/tool. Will let you know if I get anything.